# What is the conditional distribution of a normal summand given the sum?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

Suppose that I have 2 independently distributed normal random variables, $A \sim N(\mu_A, \sigma^2_A)$ and $B \sim N(\mu_B, \sigma^2_B)$. I do not observe either of these variables. What I observe is their sum, $C=A+B$. Given a value of the sum, $C=c$, what is the conditional distribution of $A$ (or $B$)? I am hoping that there is a closed form analytical solution for this question which is a function of the 5 parameters: $\mu_A, \sigma^2_A,\mu_B, \sigma^2_B, c$.

Also, if it is possible, what I am really interested in is the case where $A$ and $B$ are log-normally distributed. But from what I can tell [working with sums of lognormal variables is complicated](https://www.soa.org/globalassets/assets/files/static-pages/research/arch/2009/arch-2009-iss1-dufresne.pdf). So an answer for the case of normality would suffice.

Comment: For your first question, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/9071/intuitive-explanation-of-contribution-to-sum-of-two-normally-distributed-random which says you get a conditional normal distribution with $$\mu_{X|c} = \mu_X + (c - \mu_X - \mu_Y)\frac{ \sigma_X^2}{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}$$ $$\sigma_{X|c} = \sigma_{Y|c} = \sqrt{ \frac{\sigma_X^2 \sigma_Y^2}{\sigma_X^2 + \sigma_Y^2}}.$$

Comment: Thanks, the solution for the case of normality is exactly what I am looking for. I will add that for the case of log-normality, I could make do with a method of numerically approximating the conditional distributions, if analytical solutions are not feasible.